# Parse.com data caching and synchronization

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, synchronization

What is the best strategy to synchronize Parse objects across the application?

Take Twitter as an example, they have many Tweet objects, same tweet object can be shown on multiple places, say viewController1 and viewController2, so it is not efficient for both of them to hold deep copies of the same parse object.

When I increase the likeCount of Tweet_168 in viewController2, how should I update the likeCount of Tweet_168 in viewController1?

I created a singleton container class (TweetContainer) so every Parse request goes through this and this checks if the incoming objectIds are already in the container,
A) if it is, it updates the previous object's fields and dumps the new object. (to keep **single** deep copy of a parse object.)
B) if it is not, it adds the new object.
(This process is fast as I'm using hashmaps)

This container holds deep copies to those objects, and gives shallow copies to viewControllers, thus editing a Tweet in a viewController will result in its update on all viewControllers!

Taking one step further, let's say Tweet objects have pointers to Author objects. When an Author object is updated, I want all of them to be updated (say image change). I can create a new AuthorContainer with the same strategy and give shallow copies to Tweet objects in TweetContainer.

I could, in an **ideal** world, propagate every update to cloud and refresh every object before showing to user over the cloud, but that's not feasible neither bandwidth nor latency-wise